# I want to verify token and then verify some role using verifytoken middleware in verifyRole middleware, I got an error "verifytoken is not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

---

I want to verify token and then verify  some role using verifytoken middleware in  veygiyRole middleware, I got an error "veryIfytoken is not found"

---

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const ErrorResponse = require("../utils/ErrorResponse");

exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    !req.headers["authorization"]
  ) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse("you are not authorize", 403));
  }
  const [Bearer, token] = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ");

  if (token === null || Bearer !== "Bearer")
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Token", 403));

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(new ErrorResponse("Token is not valid", 403));
    req.user = user;
    console.log(user);
    next();
  });
};

exports.verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.role === "admin") {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(new ErrorResponse("you are not authorize", 403));
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not accessing `verifyToken` and `verifyUser` anywhere outside the current context you can modify your function as follows

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const ErrorResponse = require("../utils/ErrorResponse");

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  if (
    !req.headers["authorization"]
  ) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse("you are not authorize", 403));
  }
  const [Bearer, token] = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ");

  if (token === null || Bearer !== "Bearer")
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Token", 403));

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(new ErrorResponse("Token is not valid", 403));
    req.user = user;
    console.log(user);
    next();
  });
};

const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.role === "admin") {
      next();
    } else {
      return next(new ErrorResponse("you are not authorize", 403));
    }
  });
};
```

and if you want to access these function outside of the current context you do so with

```
module.exports = {
     verifyToken,
     verifyUser
}
```

hope this helps :)